# Create an infomation map as union of differnet oracle tables

Tags: sas

Is it possible to create an infomation map that use a union of oracle tables as source data?

We have a few tables with simliar structure, we would like to gather the common columns and present as an infomation map.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (but stack expects answers of at least 30 characters)